# I dont know how to deal with this python error TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, tuples

I have searched other threads and questions with the similar problem and from what i see the problem arises when your variables have the same identifier as a built in function, but i have tried or sorts of name for my identifiers it still didn't work...   I am very new to python so i may not be familiar with complicated terminology used i python

```
grades = [('A', 90), ('B', 70), ('C', 50), ('D', 30), ('F', 0)]
while True:
    score = int(input('Enter grade: '))
    for counter in grades:
        if score >= counter(2):
            fingrade = (counter(1))
            break
    print('This student got an ' + fingrade)
```

this is the error

```
if score >= counter(2):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: `counter(2)` is an attempt to call a function (or other callable object) referred to by `counter`, passing it a single parameter with a value of 2.  What you appear to want instead is *indexing*, to get the elements of the tuple - which is written like `counter[2]`.  But that's invalid for a different reason: your tuples all have two elements, and the indexes of those two elements are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the elements using square brackets like this `counter[2]`

When you write `counter(2)` python thinks you want to call `counter` as  a function hence the error.

Also tuples are zero-indexed, so first element is actually `counter[0]` and second is `counter[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing elements in the tuple incorrectly. Use square brackets instead of round ones, as round brackets imply a function call. By writing `counter(2)` Python thinks that you are trying to call a function `counter` with `2` as an argument. However, `counter` represents a tuple which is not callable.

Also, upon fixing this error you'll notice that your indexes are off by 1, as tuple indexes are 0-based.

The following code should fix the problems.

```
grades = [('A', 90), ('B', 70), ('C', 50), ('D', 30), ('F', 0)]

while True:
    score = int(input('Enter grade: '))
    for counter in grades:
        if score >= counter[1]:
            fingrade = (counter[0])
            break

    print('This student got an ' + fingrade)
```